# Why is my Godot Scene referencing incorrect object instances?

Tags: godot

After closing and reopening the Godot editor, objects in my scene reference the wrong resource. I have Wall nodes in my scene which reference the Wall.tscn at first, but once I close and open Godot, the Wall nodes turn into wasp.glb objects.

[image: Wall node referencing wasp.glb]

What could be causing this?

Comment: Facing the same issue, did you ever figure this out? I've tried creating a new project and changing the way I import.